# InfoPath Form browser based form

Tags: infopath

In InfoPath form, user will fill some detail and by clicking the button, it will get data with image from list and display in InfoPath form.

How we can do that?

Do we have to write custom coding for that? My form are browser based form of InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

- In the 'Data' tab, click on 'From SharePoint List' and add the list from where you need the data to be pulled from.
- Create a rule on the button, to query the secondary list which was added in the data connections
- And subsequent rules, 'Set a fields values' where you can update the fields value from secondary data source based on 'filter the data'

Comment: In browser based form image control is not working so we have to do it from coding I guess